# Keeping an organised record of emails with external parties

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

We do software development and use emails for formal communication with the client and their other suppliers. Two things are essential:

1. Such emails are public to our own team, i.e. if I send an email or receive one my PM and other developers can see it
2. emails are easily findable for a specific feature/bug ID

What we do now is create a public folder in Outlook for each feature we discuss. Whenever we send or receive emails, we copy them into the relevant folder.

It works but it's unchanged since the last century and I wondered if modern Outlook features such as tagging might help. It's not needed for this to be automated but it would be nice if it could be semi-automated, so simply tagging an email also makes it public/shared.

We're running Outlook 2010 against MS Exchange (I don't know the exact version but our server is Win 2008).

Comment: not sure if this should maybe be on ServerFault?

Comment: I'd argue no, as this is about the end-user point of software. Now if you find a solution here, and have questions about actually implementing it on a company server, that would go to [SF]. In any case, the community will find it a proper home. :)

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with this question... it asks for a solution to a specific scenario.

Comment: I think it has to do with how it's asked. Instead of "We're doing X, what improvements have been made in the last 10 years?", try "We need a way to manage correspondence with our customers better. We've been using X, but it's not working well because of Y. What is this kind of software called?" - Expect to get leads and then go research for what will suit you best. The issue is while it's a specific situation, the answers are subjective at best - there's no "right" one, and they change frequently as new projects come and go.

Comment: And to help give you a boost in the right direction, you're looking for "ticketing", "ticket management", "issue management", or "bug-tracking" solutions. There is a very wide array of such, and only your organization can truly decide what will work best.

Comment: @Darth Android: ..or indeed a Customer Relationship Managment (CRM) system since this is to improve and/or record communications with customers, as well as improve sharing, collaboration and discovery within the internal users.

Comment: OK I'll try a better phrasing of the question sometime. However I am specifically looking for how/if Outlook can be used better, not for an external tool. Thanks for the tips!